# splitting strings after detected vowels

Tags: java, string

I'm trying to split words into syllables, but the kind of syllables in my langauge (Setswana). The syllables appear each and every time after a vowel e.g. in "motho" (which means person) syllables are "mo" and "tho". They are separated by vowel, so identifying a vowel is a major key

I need a code that identifies a vowel and splits a part of a word, 1 VOWEL PER SYLLABLE...this is what i have so far:

```
public void syllable(String word)
{
    int i=0;
    int z=0;
    for (i=i;i<word.length()-1; i++){
        char w = word.charAt(i);
        String w1=Character.toString(w);
        if(w=='a'|| w=='e' || w=='i' || w=='o' || w=='u')
        {
            String[] x= word.split(w1,2);

            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(x));
            //z=i;
            continue;
        }
        continue;
    }
}
```

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: I don't think the downvoters share your excitement...

Comment: @JBNizet I'm guessing "how to actually match a statement for vowels and split after each detected vowel"

Comment: When you debug this, in what way does it not work?  Where are you stuck?  I imagine finding the vowel is going to be the easy part... Determining which *consonants* to split in between the vowels will be a bit more tricky.

Comment: "how to actually match a statement for vowels and split after each detected vowel" IS RIGHT! MY problem is! that when i try to separate a word like "kamoso"(which means tommorow)! i dnt get what im suppose to get which is suppose to be "ka" "mo" "so"!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is a complicated regular expression concept, but what you want to do is use a positive look-behind as a split:

```
String[] syllables = word.split("(?<=[aeiou])");
```

Which, for me, produces:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    for (String word : new String[]{"Motho", "Botswana"}) {
        System.out.println("Word " + word + " Syllables " 
                + Arrays.toString(word.split("(?<=[aeiou])")));
    }
}
```

and output:

```
Word Motho Syllables [Mo, tho]
Word Botswana Syllables [Bo, tswa, na]
```

**Update:** About the split, using a positive look-behind: This [regex tutorial does a better job than I can do here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).

The Java Pattern documentation is light on detail, but you want [zero-width positive lookbehind](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)

Comment: Zhuinden thats great! thanks it acutally works! bt can you explain to me how that method works

Comment: how do i put the syllables into an actual array?

Comment: @foxxy http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-

Comment: String[] parts= syllables.split(",");
         System.out.println(Arrays.toString(parts));

Comment: @foxxy - the very first code snippet in my answer does exactly what you want with respect to putting the syllables in to an actual array...